# Load an Image in a TableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to load an image from a url to the productimage, but my code does not work.
 How can I load images into `tableViewCells`?

```swift
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellWomanSaved") as! WomanSavedTableViewCell

    let Data: DataModel

    Data = DataList[indexPath.row]

    cell.priceLabel.text = Data.Price
    cell.productLabel.text = Data.ImageURL
    cell.productImage.image = UIImage(data: url)

    if let url = URL(string: productLabel[indexPath.row]) {

        do {

            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            self.swipeImage.image = UIImage(data: data)

        }catch let error {

            print(" Error : \(error.localizedDescription)")

        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: In your code you assign image before downloading . the variable "url" used before it declared. Does this code build and run successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
if let url = URL(string: productLabel[indexPath.row]) {
```

To

```
   if let url = URL(string: productLabel[indexPath.row].addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)) {
```

Comment: cell.productImage.image = UIImage(data: url)
        
        
        if let url = URL(string: productLabel[indexPath.row].addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!) {
            
            
            
            do {
                
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                self.swipeImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
                
            }catch let error {
                
                print(" Error : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                
     
            }
            
        }

Comment: dont work.. cause the cell.productimage.imgae don't find the let url and there a also a error by let data / try data. Can you fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SDWebImage** library to easily load the image from URL and show it in imageView. SDWebImage is very convenient as it download and cache the image and next time when you want the image from same URL it loads it from the cache.

It's really easy to use. You can add this to your project through cocoapod, carthage or manually the library code to your project.

Here is the link to the github repo :

https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

- Create data task in your cell
- Cancel data task in prepareForReuse function
- Pass your url to cell in your Controller cellForRowAt function
- So populate your cell with model and set values to properties

  ```
  class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

      // MARK: - Outlets

      @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var productLabel: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!


      /// create dataTask for cancel in prepareForReuse function
      private var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?

      /// Like this
      override public func prepareForReuse() {
         super.prepareForReuse()
          dataTask?.cancel()
      }

      func populate(with model: YourModel) {
          priceLabel.text = model.Price
          productLabel.text = model.ImageUrl

          /// You should set url in indexPath of your logo array([ImageUrl])
          let url = model.ImageUrl /// It's sample url for explain this is an url of your current index model
          if let imageUrl = url {
              downloaded(from: imageUrl)
          }
      }

      func downloaded(from url: URL, contentMode mode: UIView.ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
          contentMode = mode
          dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
              guard
                  let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                  let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                  let data = data, error == nil,
                  let image = UIImage(data: data)
                  else { return }
              DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                  self.productImage.image = image
              }
          }
          dataTask?.resume()
      }
  }
  ```

In your Controller's tableView cellForRowAt function:

```
let model: DataModel = DataList[indexPath.row]
cell.populate(with: model)

return cell
```